# Building an web app to run inside other apps through a JS code-snippet

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, code-snippets

I was given the task to develop sliders/pop-ups for customers of the company I work for. This works a bit like chatbots (ie. Intercom). The user sees a small bubble on the bottom-right corner, clicks on it and it shows some information from our (Rails) app.

What's the best way to create a javascript code to share with those clients? Should I add my code to a public js file and send those clients a script targeting my app? (like the example below?)

```
<script src='https://www.myapp.com/script.js'></script>
```

I've tried to do so, but it looks like the script doesn't link to my CSS files, so styles are broken. So I am not sure if it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the right approach.

To fix your missing CSS you could adjust your script to add the required CSS references to the `head` of the page.

```js
let externalCssLink = document.createElement('link')
externalCssLink.rel = 'stylesheet'
externalCssLink.href = 'https://some-external-domain.com/some-css.css'

document.head.appendChild(externalCssLink)
```